# Python QR Code Reader. Exclusively listen to input() by keyboard

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard, usb, evdev

I would like my python script to listen only to the QR Code Reader which is detected as keyboard.
I don't want the keyboard to write to the console or somewhere. Only the python script should listen to that keyboard on Linux. Is that possible? Is there a library or udev rules can prevent such thing?

```
while True:
   qr_code = input()
   logging.info(qr_code)
```

I also tried python-evdev. Where I can bind only to the device with `dev.grab_context():`. It works and receive the single key events, but I don't have the mappings. So `input()` is the easiest way for me.

```
    qr_device_path = None
    qr_device_name = "SM SM-2D PRODUCT HID KBW"
    qr_device_phys = None

    devices = [evdev.InputDevice(path) for path in evdev.list_devices()]
    # QR Code Reader name: SM SM-2D PRODUCT HID KBW
    for device in devices:
        print(device.path, device.name, device.phys)
        if(device.name == "SM SM-2D PRODUCT HID KBW"):
            logging.info("found qr code reader")
            qr_device_path = device.path
            qr_device_phys = device.phys

    if(qr_device_path):
        dev = InputDevice(qr_device_path)
        while True:
            for event in dev.read_loop():
                if event.type == ecodes.EV_KEY:
                    print(categorize(event))
```